# Saving list of plots to Powerpoint slides in latest R version 3.6

Tags: r, ggplot2, reporters

I have a list of plots which I do want to save to powerpoint slides and I found this example [Export several plots from R to ppt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545027/export-several-plots-from-r-into-ppt)  but the challenge is with latest version of R 3.6 I can't install ReporteRs package because it was removed. Would like to know if there is any other option to get me the results I need or if anyone has successfully accomplished this with latest R version

Comment: You could use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51158486/create-sections-through-a-loop-with-knitr . build a powerpoint from markdown and use the approaches given in the answers to define the chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the "graph2ppt" from the "export" package may provide the desired solution. Below a link to a post where it is explained. Keep in mind that this is a work-a-round. I have also not found a more direct solution to the above stated problem.

Post: [ggplot2 png in fullscreen Powerpoint on secondary screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089104/ggplot2-png-in-fullscreen-powerpoint-on-secondary-screen)

Demo: https://github.com/tomwenseleers/export